# how to vlookup Multiple sheets and delete set of ID's from all sheets

Tags: excel, vba

i have 12 sheets in workbook in that sheet8 is the sheet where all the sheets vlookup with, in sheet8 i have only one column with list of Customer name.

now i want what all 11 sheets should vlookup with sheet8 and what ever the names matches with sheet8 should be there which are not matching should be deleted.in these sheets 3 are empty.

## code is below

```
Sub VLdelete()

    Dim arr(), msg As String
    Dim ws_lrow, ws8_lrow, i As Integer
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    ws8_lrow = Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ReDim arr(ws8_lrow)

    For i = 2 To ws8_lrow
        arr(i - 2) = Sheets("Sheet8").Cells(i, 1).value
    Next i

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        ws_lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = ws_lrow To 2 Step -1
            If IsInArray(ws.Cells(i, 2), arr()) = 0 Then
                msg = msg & "User """ & ws.Cells(i, 2) & """ from: " & ws.Name & vbCrLf
                ws.Cells(i, 2).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
            End If
        Next i
    Next ws

    If Len(msg) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "The following users have been deleted:" & vbCrLf & msg
    End If

End Sub

Private Function IsInArray(valToBeFound As Variant, arr As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim element As Variant
    On Error GoTo IsInArrayError: 'array is empty
     For Each element In arr
            If element = valToBeFound Then
                IsInArray = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next element
    Exit Function

IsInArrayError:
    On Error GoTo 0
    IsInArray = False

End Function
```

but i am getting delete method of range class failed error ...at line no 24

```
ws.Cells(i, 2).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
```

can anyone help

Comment: I suspect it's due to many of your line are not fully qualified `ws_lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row` should be `ws_lrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row` , and many other places. Are you getting a value for `ws_lrow` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the shorter code version below.

You can replace your `Function IsInArray` with `Application.Match`.

`If Not IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(i, 2), arr, 0)) Then` checks if there is a match of current `.Cells(i, 2)` value with one of the array elements `arr` **>>** If there is it will pass this `If` criteria.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub VLdelete()

    Dim arr As Variant
    Dim msg As String
    Dim ws_lrow As Long, ws8_lrow As Long, i As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Sheets("Sheet8")
        ws8_lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        ' populate array without loop
        ' use Transpose to get 1-D array (and not 2-D)
        arr = Application.Transpose(.Range("A2:A" & ws8_lrow))
    End With

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.Name <> "Summary" Then ' skip "Summary" sheet
            With ws
                ws_lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

                For i = ws_lrow To 2 Step -1
                    ' check that no match was found >> delete user
                    If IsError(Application.Match(.Cells(i, 2), arr, 0)) Then
                        msg = msg & .Cells(i, 2) & vbCrLf
                        .Cells(i, 2).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
                    End If
                Next i
            End With
        End If
    Next ws
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    If Len(msg) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "The following users have been deleted:" & vbCrLf & msg
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: ...as usual thanks for the quick response....i have macro which running multiple macro at a time ....so i don't want  message to be  populated as "The following users have been deleted:" its better it just delete all user id's which are not matching ..can delete ' If Len(msg) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "The following users have been deleted:" & vbCrLf & msg
    End If '

Comment: @Kittu I'm not following, is my code above works as you intended ? what exactly not working with the `MsgBox` ?

Comment: ..i don't want message to be displayed what id's have been deleted ....as i have other macros which run after this completes ..hope you  got it now...and its taking long time ...its still going on after 2 to 3 min

Comment: I've added `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` , it should run faster, and I;m not following you on the `MsgBox` , can you edit your post, and add what you want to your `MsgBox` to show

Comment: .....the code is not working....i manually checked doing vlookup in all sheets and non id got deleted ...and about message once the macro complete we get one message what are all id's got deleted ....but i dont want that message to be displayed once macro is completed

Comment: i doubt its doing other way what i want....just want to make it clear that i want keep the id's which matches with sheet8  and remaining all should be deleted in all sheets ....i think its deleting what ever matches because when i done vlookup manually ...i got all #N/A

Comment: @Kittu  you want to keep the ones that match and delete the ones that don't ?

Comment: @Kittu try the edited code -  should work the way you wanted

Comment: ....it seems working ..i checked at home with dummy data .....tomorrow i check with live data at office and confirm you..thanks once again

Comment: Today i tried on live data its showing  Run time error 1004 "delete method of range class failed "  at line no: 27

Comment: what is line 27 ? can you tell me at what line ?

Comment: ...in my sheets i have a sheet named summary and its protected .when i unprotected it  and tried again code started working..is there anyway i can skip the sheet named "Summary" from vlookup

Comment: @Kittu this type of information is **CRUCIAL** as this is related to your workbook structure, and there's no way for me to guess it is. Try the edited code to skip the "Summary" sheet.

Comment: what you said is absolutely right....but i forgot that and realized when i ran the code...now its working perfectly.....and skipping the Summary sheet